# PostScript - Generate text using uninstalled fonts

Tags: text, fonts, postscript

I want to generate text using postscript and some font file. I can convert the font to whatever needed font type necessary. The catch is, I can't install the font on the computer - there are certain limitations on the computer that would be way to long to explain, just know that the end result means that I can't install the font.
I am aware of the fact that t42 fonts are generated as a glorified eps file, however, I am not looking to simply append the font to the file - I have more than 1 font I am doing this to.

Are there hacky work arounds for the end goal?

Comment: This is going to be product specific. Even accessing "installed" fonts is implementation specific to some extent. Are you using Ghostscript or something else?

Comment: At the moment ghostscript on my personal computer. I think my linux / unix box (the machine that doesn't have any admin rights) has some kind of php postscript interpreter installed on it. I haven't tested it out. I think going forward, I may just have to read the t42, stick it in the file and say, "okay, good enough", despite how big the file will be. You dont happen to be aware of any php solution for an eps to pdf conversion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know of any. But the unix box is almost certainly using Ghostscript under the hood. I believe Ghostscript falls back to using the `fontconfig` library to find fonts that are not part of the gs distribution. The fontconfig tool `fc-list` will show you the fonts it can find and you may need to look at the output to find an appropriate PostScript name to request the font.